# Why doesn't the loader find defined references? (Ceedling embedded testing)

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded, ceedling

everyone!
I'd like to ask your kind support for testing my embedded software with Ceedling.

I am new to this world, so please be gentle!

I have set up a Docker container with Ceedling, offered by throwtheswitch.org. I could import every source file in the "src" directory, including vendor drivers and ARM libraries and was able to run my first test.

Here comes the hard part: I must test a function that interacts with the underlying hardware, so when I tried to test it, it failed because I was accessing illegal addresses on Windows.

I noticed that the driver's vendor has included native testing definitions for cases like this:
[image: There is a new definition for every peripheral]

So I added the UNIT_TESTING_OCN define to Ceedling's project.yml file under "common_defines". On VSCode, I included the same define, and as you can see from the screenshot, original defines are dimmed out.

Nevertheless, when running "ceedling test:all", the linker loader cannot find the references:
[image: Undefined references]

If I press F12 in VSCode it brings me to the new definition included in the #else preprocessor statement. So what gives?

Why can't Ceedling correctly run?

Please ask for more information, I am sure I have missed something you might need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I would assume you need to include some additional test library or some C file holding the definitions of those symbols. Your vendor should explain how that Unit test support is supposed to be used.

Comment: "I must test a function that interacts with the underlying hardware" Obviously testing must be done on the intended hardware, everything else is utter nonsense. If your task is to test the max speed of a certain car in an outdoors environment, then putting a car seat on the back of a horse, spray paint "car" on the side of the horse and then check how fast the horse can run in some indoors arena is just about as relevant as trying to test embedded microcontroller code on MS Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is compiled when `UNIT_TESTING_OCN` is defined just declares `extern` for those symbols so that the compiler will believe they exist. You're not actually defining any variables at all. Hence why linking fails.

You should define the actual variables in the test code that uses them.

e.g. I have a test_rtc.c file in one of my projects, which contains:

```c
RTC_HandleTypeDef      hrtc;
ADC_HandleTypeDef      hadc1;
```

It sounds like you might want to have something like the following in your tests:

```c
static ADC1_Type MyADC1;
ADC1_Type *ADC1 = &MyADC1;
```

etc.

Comment: These declarations don't seem to be added by the OP. They just defined the UNIT_TESTING_OCN flag

Comment: No, you cannot just add these declarations out of the blue and out of any context. These are very likely structs corresponding to memory mapped hardware registers. They need to be allocated at specific fixed addresses only available on the target hardware. Just because you declare a variable named `MyADC1`, you do not magically get compatible ADC hardware added to your desktop PC. We cannot test embedded microcontroller programs on a PC.

Comment: @lundin - I'm well aware of that. Still this is about the only way you can test such code (in a framework like Ceedling). For example to stub a function like `HAL_ADC_Start(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hdma...)` you need to be have an ADC structure to pass the address of. This is how you would do it. Your stubbed functions would emulate the ADC to some extent. Of course you would not have a real ADC on your PC.

Comment: No. You cannot test such code in a "framework" at all. There is not much to "test suite" around with in low-level driver code, it's usually just a bunch of register writes and the most important thing to check is if the registers are set correctly and if the ADC etc hardware behaves as expected. Or are you seriously suggesting that testers should test if the person who wrote the code managed to correctly set a bit in a 8 bit register? That sounds like kindergarten - hire competent engineers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded ARM microcontrollers cannot be tested meaningfully on a hosted system PC like Windows or Linux. Various "test suite" fluffware cannot be used. Just forget about it.

Instead, embedded systems testings should be done like this:

- Test on the actual live MCU intended for the project. Not on a PC, not in a simulator.
- Test with the actual live hardware that the MCU requires to function meaningfully. Most of the time this means on a custom PCB.
- There is no "isolating software from hardware". Rather you should test both of these at the same time, to test the real world application as it will eventually be delivered. Tests should be based on functionality, not on parts of the code. Ideally, tests should also be against requirements in the specification.

So for example if you are to test if the ADC is working correctly, then a sensible test could be designed as:

- Measure the Vref voltage for the ADC with your oscilloscope. Is it within specified acceptable levels? Is it stable?
- Arrange a test voltage from some external source and add it to an ADC input pin. Measure it to ensure it is stable and then compare it with the values read by the ADC driver. Do they match, given the specified ADC resolution?
- Do the above test with a long series of samples. Check for fluctuations in the ADC result. What's the largest fluctuation you can catch? What's acceptable as per the specification?
- Maybe design a software trap in case the ADC fluctuation values goes outside the valid ranges and then leave the system on for x hours.
- In case it fails, was it because of hardware or software? Maybe the Vref or signal is picking up noise from some switching regulator? Or maybe there are rounding errors in the software?

And so on. And no, separating software tests from hardware tests and do the software tests on some PC is still nonsense. Suppose the bug was a software rounding error, then you still can't catch it on the PC, because it might use different sized integers, different FPU, different arithmetic instructions altogether.

And why on earth should you force the dev to write code portable to a PC just so that some irrelevant "test suite" can execute it? That's a nonsense requirement which just adds complexity and extra work that nobody wants to pay for.

Comment: Testing on real hardware is of course required, but I'd disagree that it's pointless writing unit tests for a framework that runs on a PC. I've done it for a mid-scale project with 100% line and branch coverage, and uncovered a few tens of bugs that way. (Many were found just through the process of writing the tests, not even running them.) I don't feel it was pointless.

Comment: I would not be that assertive about not testing on the PC. What about when the hardware is not available yet but you still have to develop the software?  Agreed, you still have to test the end product. But the business logic can well be tested on a host PC provided you have meaningful hardware abstractions. It can save you a lot of time and money, especially if malfunctioning software can ruin the hardware, if the physical process is very long (e.g. controlling the T° of a 100k liters tank), or if you have to deal with exceptional states that may be difficult to reach on the real system.

Comment: @pmacfarlane You can't test code coverage on a PC either, because it cannot generate interrupts. And there's no reason why you can't do such tests directly on the target. But sure, things like static analysis of code coverage doesn't require any particular hardware. Dynamic analysis does, however.

Comment: @emiled The way embedded systems are usual designed: write the specification, look at suitable microcontrollers, pick one, order an evaluation board, start with program design stage while fine-tuning the specification, the board arrives, start hacking drivers. And that usually keeps you well-busy until the first custom PCB prototype is there. Sure, I've done my share of hacking down artificial simulators on a PC just to test an algorithm. They tend to get increasingly irrelevant the closer to the end product you get.

Comment: @emiled I've done projects that are very similar to your example, such as controlling the speed of a concrete drum on a truck and thereby controlling the flow of concrete. A few parts of the application were safety-critical. I did start by writing a simple graphic simulator in a PC since we didn't have access to a truck. It was irrelevant. Then we build a mechanical lab thing to test sensors. It was less irrelevant but still far from the end product. We couldn't get any actual work done until we were given access to a real truck. Until then we had just been fumbling around in the dark.

Comment: Bottom line: there's lots of myths that you can actually develop embedded systems without access to the real hardware. Sure you can try, but you will not likely produce anything of quality.

Comment: @Lundin All I can really say is that I've tested projects in Ceedling, including simulating interrupts, perfectly successfully. It can certainly be done, and was useful. Have you tried Ceedling?